# Gridview always return a single row

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using the below code to display some records in gridview with specific filter. If the parent less than 2 means records display in a grid. But it always return a single row but my last datatable dt having more than five rows.How can i solve this error

```
try
{
    DataView dv = new DataView();
    dv = dt.DefaultView;
    dv.RowFilter = "FLD_PARENT=0";
    if (dv.Count < 2)
    {
        dv_pack.Visible = true;
        dt.DefaultView.Sort = "FLD_TYPE";
        grd_pack.DataSource = dt;
        grd_pack.DataBind();
     }
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
     throw;
 }
```

Comment: can you check or post here how you retrieve data from database?

Comment: What is your Query. try to count return row. Issue with your QUery.

Comment: My function like this "private void load_pack(DataTable dt)"

Comment: I guess, this is not a `GridView` issue. Please add some details how you arrive with passed DataTable value in that method.

Comment: if you take out the RowFilter line, do you get more than 5 rows? if yes, please review your RowFilter

Comment: Check how many rows you are left with after applying RowFilter. Also just for testing comment the RowFilter line and see if you are getting the result in the way you want

Comment: yes correct, I removed the row filter its working fine. But i want to add the rowfilter also.